# ASP.NET MVC 4 multi tenancy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multi-tenant, hobo

In ASP.NET MVC 4 I see that there is and [Authorize] attribute and now a corresponding [AllowAnonymous] attribute that can easily let you require authentication to access specific controller actions.

What I need is true multi tenancy though. Each user can access only their own records, and all records other than the user accounts should be owned by individual users.

In Hobo (http://hobocentral.net) which is a Rails plugin, this was easily accomplished by adding the following line of code in my ApplicationController:

```
before_filter :login_required, :except => [:login, :signup, :do_signup, :activate]
```

And then in my model:

```
belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User", :creator => true

# --- Permissions --- #

def create_permitted?
  acting_user == owner || !owner_changed?
end

def update_permitted?
  acting_user == owner || !owner_changed?
end

def destroy_permitted?
  acting_user == owner || !owner_changed?
end

def view_permitted?(field)
  owner_is? acting_user or new_record?
end
```

And finally in my model's controller:

```
def index
  hobo_index current_user.modelName
end
```

Does something so simple and elegant exist or is built into ASP.NET MVC? So far I've found several ways to implement multi tenancy in ASP.NET MVC but I'm unsure as to which is the clearly correct way. I also intent to use .NET 4.5 and Entity Framework 5 if that helps.

Answer (score -2):

if you are using any type of built in authentication in asp.net MVC then its already present as you can use something like

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

and if you are not using some kind of internal authentication mechanism then you can do what i did simple when authentication a user save the primary key in a `session` variable.

```
Session["User"] = Key;
```

and inside each controller take out the variable

```
var key = Session["User"];
```

and retrive the user data based on the key

Comment: Plus you can also think of writing a simple ModelBinder to have automatically loaded that information without the use of magic string

Comment: Thanks. One line of code "HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name" doesn't really tell me how to create a multi tenant application. Is there a tutorial, a code sample, etc?

Comment: I would agree with Jeremy in that this answer doesn't remotely attempt to cover how to do true multi-tenancy. There are many ways to skin that cat, but this answer is not one of those.